# Magento Connect Manager issue

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect-manager

I am having trouble getting my credentials to work for the mage connect. I have read several articles that say to delete the cache.cfg and the connect.cfg which I don't seem to have those files. I also tried to upload a new downloader folder and that will not work either. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this fixed partly. It seems it was a cookie issue. I went incognito in chrome and connect Manager came right up.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! What worked for me was setting

brute-force-bad-attempts-count = 0
in var/brute-force.ini

Source: https://dx3webs.com/blog/access-is-locked